# XAML TabControl Border Issues

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border

I am trying to make a custom `TabControl` that supports scrolling but keeps the original look and feel of the `TabControl`, obviously with the exception that it scrolls.

To begin I chose to edit a copy of the original template `TabControl` used.

Then I put a `ScrollViewer` around the `TabPanel`. However, this has caused a minor issue where the tabs now have a border at the bottom of them when they are selected. This can be seen below by comparing the normal `TabControl` and the styled `TabControl` in the image.

At first I assumed this was the z indexing of the scroll viewer but after trying different values and making sure the z index of the scroll viewer and `TabPanel` are both explicitly higher than the `Border`'s z index, it made no difference.

How can I achieve the same effect where there is no border at the bottom of the selected tab, whilst it is wrapped in a `ScrollViewer`?

[image]

---

*MainWindow.xaml*

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollableTabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
        <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                          Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                          Background="Transparent">
                                <TabPanel IsItemsHost="true"
                                          Margin="2,2,2,0"
                                          Panel.ZIndex="2"
                                          Background="Transparent"
                                          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                          x:Name="headerPanel"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Border x:Name="contentPanel"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    Panel.ZIndex="0"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                                  ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Margin="5"
                    Grid.Row="0">
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 3"/>
        </TabControl>
        <TabControl Margin="5"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}">
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 3"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Refer the link [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/485099/Styling-WPF-TabControl-Borders). I think the above mentioned link solve your problem.

Comment: @Gokul Thank you for the link. I will look into it. On quick glance though, it looks like it uses set row sizes and things that would break the `TabStripPlacement` property behaviour. Obviously it could probably be modified to work with this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if we go take a look at a `ScrollViewer` [style template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/scrollviewer-styles-and-templates) notice there's a `Border` in there with a set color for it which is the artifact you're seeing.

We could go in and edit a Style template of ScrollViewer and remove that....or for this instance we could just let it keep its Border and override the style inheritance so in your template you could do something like;

```
 <ScrollViewer ...>
    <ScrollViewer.Resources>
      <Color x:Key="BorderMediumColor">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
    </ScrollViewer.Resources>
 ....
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Wherein it should inherit that new color for the `Border` in there which in this case I just made white, or you could change the alpha channel too '00' so it's just transparent. Or you could do the previously mentioned and define a new style template without the hardcoded border values.

Hope this helps, cheers!

ADDENDUM : If you can't find the culprit causing the visual border line you can always sort of cheat with the layout of elements within the DOM and utilize margins to overlay the line and achieve the same desired visual result. The line may still technically exist but the illusion that it doesn't can suffice just the same. :)

---

Working code example

```
<Window x:Class="ScrollableTabControl.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Background" Color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TabItem.Selected.Border" Color="#ACACAC"/>
        <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Background}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.Selected.Border}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot"
                              ClipToBounds="true"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                              KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                              UseLayoutRounding="True"> <!-- Gets rid of pixel rounding errors which cause small bugs when window is a certain size -->
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition0"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnDefinition1" Width="0"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition0" Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowDefinition1" Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                          Grid.Column="0"
                                          Grid.Row="0"
                                          Panel.ZIndex="1"
                                          Margin="0, 0, 0, -1.25"
                                          Background="Transparent"> <!-- +- 1.25 seems to be required when mixed with the ZIndex to hide the border underneath the selected tab -->
                                <TabPanel IsItemsHost="true"
                                          Margin="2,2,2,1.25"
                                          Background="Transparent"
                                          KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                                          x:Name="headerPanel"/>
                            </ScrollViewer>
                            <Border x:Name="contentPanel"
                                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                                    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                                  ContentSource="SelectedContent"
                                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Margin="5"
                    Grid.Row="0">
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 3"/>
        </TabControl>
        <TabControl Margin="5"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Style="{DynamicResource TabControlStyle1}">
            <TabItem Header="Tab 1"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 2"/>
            <TabItem Header="Tab 3"/>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for the answer. However, I do believe the default `ScrollViewer` template does not contain a border.

Comment: I'd be curious where that border is coming from then. I'd go pop open a default template but unfortunately I don't work in a .net/xaml shop anymore, may take a peek when I get home.

Comment: Thanks. In my initial question I talked about the zindex, and I still think that is the route cause. I believe the border comes from the border in the default `TabControl` style that has the name `contentPanel` then when a tab is selected, as it has a higher zindex it occludes the border. This can be seen if the changed zindex is removed and it then looks the same as mine. I just can't see why wrapping it in a scrollviewer affects it

Comment: Ah ok, so two things. I'd be curious about the `TabItem.Selected.Border` color you've set, and if you you couldn't just change the margin on your `TabPanel` to `Margin="2,2,2,-1"` so it scoots down just over that line...

Comment: Hi Chris. Thanks for the further suggestions. The `TabItem.Selected.Border` is the standard border as defined by the template. The code extract is literally a very slightly manipulated version of the original. And the `-1` thing kinda worked. So if on the `ScrollViewer` the margin or padding is `0, 0, 0, -1` then it hides the border. But that is on all of them.

Comment: Hi Chris, I played around with your suggestion and got it to work. By setting a padding of `0, 0, 0, -1.25` on the `ScrollViewer` and a margin of `2, 2, 2, 1.25` on the `TabPanel` it works as expected. Feel free to modify your answer and I will accept it

Comment: @Dan fair enough, done and done, have a great weekend!

Answer (score -1):

**You can try this to get custom rounded tabs with blue background**
As for scrolling, scrollviewer should do the job

```
<TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TabItem">
                            <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" Margin="2,0" Background="#252e37">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                    ContentSource="Header"
                                    Margin="10,2"/>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="GhostWhite" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer but this made no difference with the exception of changing how the tabs look